# Erro ao mostrar palavras com acento na View

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

Boa tarde,

Todas as palavras que possuem acento no meu sistema estão sendo formatadas errada como no exemplo abaixo:

> Auto de Inspe¿¿o

Onde era pra ser auto de inspeção. Como resolver isso, sabendo que estou usando c# com Razor e padrão MVC.

Comment: Onde elas aparecem assim? na View? inclua o seu código.

Comment: Na view está normal, somente acontece isso em dados vindo do banco. Uso oracle 11g e tudo que trago do banco substitui o acento por ?

Answer (score 1):

Por acaso você informou no web.config e no HTML o tipo de linguagem?
Altamente recomendável no HTML:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="language" content="pt-br" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

No ínicio do da View/HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="pt-br">
```

Web.config:

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Comment: sim ja possuo essa linha no web config da seguinte forma: <globalization culture="pt-BR" fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" uiCulture="pt-BR" />

Comment: Está usando algum banco de dados ou é um texto escrito direto na View?

Comment: banco de dados oracle